# How to add customer in the squareup payment gateway using golang?

Tags: security, go, oauth-2.0

I'm using golang to add customer in the squareup.com but it always says the probelm of the authorization Can anyone tell me that what is problem in my code:-

```
func Token(c *gin.Context) {
 code := c.Query("code")
 splitCode := strings.Split(code, "-")
 scope := c.DefaultQuery("scope", "CUSTOMERS_WRITE")
 customer := models.Customer{
    GivenName:    "Amelia",
    FamilyName:   "Earhart",
    CompanyName:  "fbgusbd",
    Nickname:     "kdfbkgjkdf",
    EmailAddress: "Amelia.Earhart@example.com",
    Address: models.Addresss{
        AddressLine1:                 "500 Electric Ave",
        AddressLine2:                 "Suite 600",
        Locality:                     "New York",
        AdministrativeDistrictLevel1: "NY",
        PostalCode:                   "10003",
        Country:                      "US",
    },
    PhoneNumber: "1-212-555-4240",
    ReferenceId: "12",
    Note:        "a customer",
 }
 fmt.Println(customer)
 bindData, err := json.Marshal(customer)
 if err != nil {
    panic(err)
 }
 var jsonStr = []byte(string(bindData))
 url := config.APIBaseLive + "v2/customers?code=" + splitCode[1] + "&scope=" + scope

 req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
 req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+splitCode[1])
 req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")
 fmt.Println("Request", req)
  client := &http.Client{}
  resp, err := client.Do(req)
 // fmt.Println(resp, err)
 if err != nil {
    panic(err)
 }
 defer resp.Body.Close()
 resp.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+splitCode[1])
 resp.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")
 fmt.Println("response Status:", resp.Status)
 fmt.Println("response Headers:", resp.Header)
 body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
 fmt.Println("response Body:", string(body))
}

type Customer struct {
  GivenName    string   `json:"given_name" bson:"given_name"`
  FamilyName   string   `json:"family_name" bson:"family_name"`
  CompanyName  string   `json:"company_name" bson:"company_name"`
  Nickname     string   `json:"nickname" bson:"nickname"`
  EmailAddress string   `json:"email_address" bson:"email_address"`
  Address      Addresss `json:"address" bson:"address"`
  PhoneNumber  string   `json:"phone_number" bson:"phone_number"`
  ReferenceId  string   `json:"reference_id" bson:"reference_id"`
  Note         string   `json:"note" bson:"note"`
}
```

Errors:-

```
 {
  "errors": [
     {
        "category": "AUTHENTICATION_ERROR",
        "code": "UNAUTHORIZED",
        "detail": "This request could not be authorized."
     }
   ]
}
```

While hitting `https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=your_client_id` then it will direct you to a url redirect url you added with a query string code having a key authenticate key. You will add the redirect url in the dashboard and then by using this code you will called a authenticate user. Can anyone help me too solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: `it always says the problem of the authorization` - what exactly happens?

Comment: make sure that you register `redirect url` in squareup. OpenID redirects only to whitelisted urls.

Comment: Not that it is contributing to your error, but why are you adding your headers to the request *and the response*?

Comment: @DmitryHarnitski when I hit `https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=your_client_id` this url then it will redirect me the redirect url Which I added in dashboard then it provide me some code string in query string of url then I use that code in my header. For that there is a valid user

Answer (score 1):

Check how oauth2 is implemented by squareup  https://docs.connect.squareup.com/authz/oauth/how-it-works

Your GO code is BACKEND on that diagram.

https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/authorize is expected to be called from CLIENT (Browser, Native or Mobile App) that will cause some HTTP redirects in browser to ask user for credentials and other challenges. These credentials are expected to be provided by human using Browser or Web View (chromeless version of browser).

You are likely getting redirect response when you send your request from GO. That is redirect to HTML page where user can enter credentials.

Do not try to implement CLIENT in GO, that should not be possible as whole `oauth2` flow assumes user input and should detect and reject backend code.

Comment: can we add a customer in the square without using oauth?